# Linear system with $\infty^{n-m}$ solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm stuck on the following teacher's notes regarding finding the solutions of a linear system by studying the rank of the matrix of the coefficients. Here's what I understand and what I don't.

**What I understand:**

The problem is to find a solution to the system $Ax=b$ in which $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix with $rank(A)=m$.

If $n>m$ and presuming that the linearly independent columns of $A$ are the columns from $1$ to $m$, $A$ can be written as:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_m & a_{m+1} & \dots & a_n \end{pmatrix}$$

If a solution exists, then b can be obtained as a linear combination of the basis vectors (columns $1$ to $m$):

$$x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots +x_ma_m=b$$

with:

$$x_{m+1}=\dots=x_n=0$$

So one solution is:

$$x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

**What I don't understand:**

$x$ is not the only solution. Consider:

$$\bar b = b-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots - x_na_n$$

with:

$$x_{m+1},\dots,x_n\in \mathbb{R}$$

Solving:

$$x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots +x_ma_m=\bar b$$

will provide with other solutions to the system.

The number of solutions is $\infty^{n-m}$ which corresponds to all the possible choices of $\bar b$.

**My question is:** since we suppose that $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\bar b$ must differ from $b$. Therefore, if $\bar x$ is a solution to $Ax=\bar b$, we have that $A\bar x=\bar b$. But if $\bar x$ is a solution to $Ax=b$, we have that $A\bar x =b$. This would mean that $\bar b=b$ which is not true.

Comment: One $x$ (for example your $\overline x$) can not solve both system $Ax=b$ and $Ax=\overline b$ at the same time when $b\neq\overline b$. How did you conclude $b=\overline b$?

Comment: @Christoph I concluded $\overline b \neq b$ since $\bar b = b-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots - x_na_n$ and $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n\in \mathbb{R}$. In the end I supposed $\overline b = b$ because I have implicitly considered $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n \neq 0$. However you made me notice that $-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots - x_na_n$ can be zero even without the unknowns being zeros because the vectors $a_{m+1},\dots ,a_n$ are linearly dependent. Finally I think that $\bar b = b-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots - x_na_n$ means that I can find all the other solutions by finding the unknowns for which $-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots - x_na_n=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exists $x$ such that $x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots +x_ma_m+x_{m+1}a_{m+1}+\dots +x_na_n=b$ with $x_{m+1}=\dots=x_n=0$. Therefore the solution is:

$$x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

You can rewrite it as $x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots +x_ma_m=b-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots -x_na_n$. **This is true as long as the quantity $-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots -x_na_n$ equals zero.**

The obvious way to cancel that quantity is to set $x_{m+1}=\dots=x_n=0$ as we did in the beginning to find $x$. But it's not the only way because **the columns $a_{m+1},\dots,a_n$ are linearly dependent.** This means there exist (infinite) sets of values $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n \neq0$ such that $-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots -x_na_n=0$.

Once you find one set you can write another solution:

$$\overline x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \\ x_{m+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$$

Indeed:

$$A\overline x= x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots +x_ma_m+x_{m+1}a_{m+1}+\dots +x_na_n= b-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots -x_na_n = b $$ because $-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots -x_na_n=0$

The number of solutions depends on the number of combinations of $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n \neq0$ such that $-x_{m+1}a_{m+1}-\dots -x_na_n=0$. The latter depends on how many unknowns are in one combination, which is $n-m$. Finally we conclude that the system has $\infty^{n-m}$ solutions to express that, although the solutions are infinite, the magnitude of the set of the solutions depends on $n-m$ unknowns.